SQL separate units and decimals from price
I have price column in MySQL contains this values :



price




1020.2200


202.0000


0.5000


820.6700



I want to split at the floating point.
Here is what I'm trying to get :



price
p_units
p_decimals




1020.2200
1020
22


202.0000
202
00


0.5058
0
50


820.6700
820
67



This is the SQL statement I've written so far :
SELECT 
    price, FLOOR(price) AS `p_units`, `price` MOD 1 AS `p_decimal` 
FROM 
    mytable

The problem is the results for p_decimal results is with "leading 0." and "4 decimal digits" instead of 2 :
0.2200
0.0000
0.5058
0.6700


This seems like a presentation concern - can you not do this in a more appropriate presentation or reporting tool, rather than trying to do it down in the database?

Why do you want 0.50 for the value 0.5058 and not 0.51?

you both had the point of view that just i diden't think about - should i review my question ?

Please explain the discrepancy between "5000" and "5058".

Please explain why having a single column of type DECIMAL(11,2) or DECIMAL(13,4) would not be a better schema.

My intial values contains those values also DECIMAL(13,4) its more precise

select FLOOR((820.6700 * 100) MOD 100);

SELECT
   price,  
   CAST(price AS SIGNED) AS p_units, 
   LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '.', -1), 2, '0') AS p_decimals 
FROM 
   YOUR_TABLE_NAME;


CAST(price AS SIGNED) : This converts the price value into an integer by removing the decimals.

CAST(1020.2200 AS SIGNED) -> 1020
CAST(202.0000 AS SIGNED) -> 202


SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '.', -1) : Extract the part of the price after the decimal point.

SUBSTRING_INDEX(1020.2200, '.', -1) -> 2200
SUBSTRING_INDEX(202.0000, '.', -1) -> 0000


LPAD(..., 2, '0') : Ensure the extracted value is at least 2 characters length by padding with zeros on the left.

LPAD('2200', 2, 0) -> 22
LPAD('6', 2, 0) -> 60
LPAD('0000', 2, 0) -> 00




Floor and a bit of processing should give the expected result.
FIDDLE
SELECT 
    price,
    FLOOR(price) AS p_units, 
    LPAD(FLOOR((price - FLOOR(price)) * 100), 2, '0') AS p_decimals
FROM 
    mytable;


The FLOOR extracts the integer part (p_units).
The fractional part is isolated and multiplied by 100, then padded with zeros if necessary to ensure exactly two digits for p_decimals.

